# Can i extract a specific character from a string stored in a list?

Tags: python, string, list

str=['qIQNlQSLi', 'eOEKiVEYj', 'aZADnMCZq', 'bZUTkLYNg', 'uCNDeHSBj', 'kOIXdKBFh']

I want to extract the 5th index of each string in list i.e o/p is linked.

Comment: [a[5] for a in str]

Comment: Don't use `str` as variable name, it will shadow the builtin `str` type. Also the name is very misleading for a list of strings...

Answer (score 3):

You could do with list comprehension,

```
string=['qIQNlQSLi', 'eOEKiVEYj', 'aZADnMCZq', 'bZUTkLYNg', 'uCNDeHSBj', 'kOIXdKBFh']

[item[5] for item in str]
```

Or you could do it much shorter like this,

```
>>> list(zip(*string))[5]
('Q', 'V', 'M', 'L', 'H', 'K')
>>>
```

If the `string` is really big, then using this iterator method would be better.

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions should work for this. However you have to check whether your string has `5th index` or not. Adding a sample code below.

```
str_list = ['qIQNlQSLi', 'eOEKiVEYj', 'aZADnMCZq', 'bZUTkLYNg', 'uCNDeHSBj', 'kOIXdKBFh']
return [item[5] for item in str_list if len(item) > 5]
```

There is a lot you could do with [List Comprehensions.](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

Comment: It should be `len(item) > 5`  or `len(item) >= 6` to check if indexes `0` to `5` exist

Answer (score 0):

you can do :

```
5thChar=[i[5] for i in str]
```

which is equivalent to :

```
5thChar=[]
for i in str:
    5thChar.append(i[5])
```